# Rails 3: Create a new record by URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, http-post

All:

What's the correct syntax for a new record to be created by passing all the parameters inside a URL, not from a Web form?

I'd like a different computer system to be able to concatenate a URL and create new records in my Rails app.

But, when I try to make a new record in "Scores", Rails won't add it.

```
    http://myapp.heroku.com/scores?message_id=51&subscriber_id=167&amount=3&method=post
```

Where the desired attributes to add to a new scores record are message_id, subscriber_id, and amount.

Here's the Heroku log

```
    2012-01-26T18:27:34+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/scores?message_id=51&subscriber_id=167&amount=3&method=submit" for 122.17.234.171 at 2012-01-26 10:27:34 -0800
    2012-01-26T18:27:34+00:00 app[web.1]:   Processing by ScoresController#index as HTML
    2012-01-26T18:27:34+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"message_id"=>"51", "subscriber_id"=>"167", "amount"=>"3", "method"=>"post"}
    2012-01-26T18:27:34+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered scores/index.html.erb within layouts/application (3.4ms)
    2012-01-26T18:27:34+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 16ms (Views: 4.2ms | ActiveRecord: 10.6ms)
    2012-01-26T18:27:34+00:00 heroku[router]: GET postopmobile.heroku.com/scores dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=55ms status=200 bytes=7605
```

Here's my Scores model

```
    class Score < ActiveRecord::Base

     belongs_to :message
     belongs_to :subscriber

    end
```

Scores controller has all the standard Rails CRUD scaffolding, plus this (I'm running Devise):

```
    before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:new, :create]
```

Lastly, trying method=submit at the end of the above URL doesn't work either.

Any thoughts?  I'm trying to figure out if it's just a syntax issue or a deeper Rails create issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

New records by default in Ruby on Rails are created using `POST`. If you want to have them created using a `GET` request (which I would advise against) you need to create a custom route to your `create` action. For more info on the routes see: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html.

Comment: Hi. thanks.  I'm not at all married to the GET..in fact I'd like to use POST.  I use don't know how to get Rails to realize I want POST.  Do I do that in a custom route?  Do I point that custom URL to the existing Create CRUD action?

Comment: Rails by default uses a POST. The sender (is it a Ruby application?) must send the request as a POST. You can make a POST using CURL (or any HTTP library) (see http://superuser.com/questions/149329/how-do-i-make-a-post-request-with-the-curl-command-line-tool).

Answer (score 0):

You need a POST request instead of GET. It will not work with passing 'method' at url.
If you really want to do that, you can add custom route, e.g.:

```
resources :scores do
 get :make
end
```

Then add 'make' action at controller, which creates new record.

But it's extremely unsafely.